# Scala:case class runTime Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This demo ran Ok. But when I move it to another class function(my former project) and call the function, it compiles failure.

```
     object DFMain {
         case class Person(name: String, age: Double, t:String)
         def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
         val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Scala Word Count")
         val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
         import sqlContext.implicits._
         val bsonRDD = sc.parallelize(("foo",1,"female")::
                                        ("bar",2,"male")::
                                     ("baz",-1,"female")::Nil)
                      .map(tuple=>{
                    var bson = new BasicBSONObject()
                    bson.put("name","bfoo")
                    bson.put("value",0.1)
                    bson.put("t","female")
                    (null,bson)
                 })
    val tDf = bsonRDD.map(_._2)
              .map(f=>Person(f.get("name").toString,
                   f.get("value").toString.toDouble,
                   f.get("t").toString)).toDF()

       tDf.limit(1).show()
 }
}
```

'MySQLDao.insertIntoMySQL()' compile error

```
object MySQLDao {
     private val sc= new SparkContext("local", "Scala Word Count")
     val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
     import sqlContext.implicits._

     case class Person(name: String, age: Double, t:String)
     def insertIntoMySQL(): Unit ={

      val bsonRDD = sc.parallelize(("foo",1,"female")::
                                     ("bar",2,"male")::
                                     ("baz",-1,"female")::Nil)
                       .map(tuple=>{
               val bson = new BasicBSONObject()
               bson.put("name","bfoo")
               bson.put("value",0.1)
               bson.put("t","female")
               (null,bson)
         })
 val tDf = bsonRDD.map(_._2).map( f=> Person(f.get("name").toString,
                                           f.get("value").toString.toDouble,
                                            f.get("t").toString)).toDF()

   tDf.limit(1).show()

 }
}
```

Will, when I call 'MySQLDao.insertIntoMySQL()' gets the Error of

value typedProductIterator is not a member of object scala.runtim.scala.scalaRuntTime

case class Person(name: String, age: Double, t:String)

Comment: Strange error. That's a Scala compiler error. Does it appear when you compile the code, or when you run it? Also, try to make the example self-contained, so people can reproduce the error. For example, BasicBSONObject is not defined.

Comment: Yes, it is compiler error. I am sorry that I give you wrong express. I created a new  project and It just done the right thing. However, I still donot know why.

Comment: Hi,  I am doing a spark project using scala. But my scala is very poor. Could you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the case class isn't seen in closure inside map function. Move it to the package level.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Double, t:String)
object MySQLDao {
...
}
```